# Waiting for object's Awake() after loading a new scene synchronously

Tags: unity, scenemanager, monobehaviour

I have a `GameScene` with an initially active `GameObject` in it, which has a singleton component:

```
public static ObjectiveManager Instance;

public void Awake()
{
    if (Instance != null && Instance != this)
    {
        Log.Info(this.GetType(), "Instance of this class already exists! CRITICAL");
    }

    ObjectiveManager.Instance = this;
}
```

Now, when I call:

```
private void StartGameScene(){
    SceneManager.LoadScene("GameScene");
    ObjectiveManager.Instance.SomeFunction(); // << singleton not initialized
}
```

I get an error, because `ObjectiveManager` is not set to an instance of an object.

As `LoadScene` is a synchronous operation so my guess was that `Awake()` is called immediately, synchronously. As I can see now, it's not.

Is there any way to determine that all of the objects on the scene have their `Awake()` already called, without checking each of them with some custom `IsReady`?

Answer (score 1):

From [Unity’s docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html):

> When using SceneManager.LoadScene, the loading does not happen immediately, it completes in the next frame. This semi-asynchronous behavior [...] can be confusing because load does not complete immediately.

So there’s no way to do it synchronously. A coroutine running on an object marked as `DontDestroyOnLoad` would be a simple alternative, although in that case, you may as well use `LoadLevelAsync`:

```
private void StartGameScene(){
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
    StartCoroutine(StartGameSceneAsync());
}
private IEnumerator StartGameSceneAsync() {
    yield return SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("GameScene");
    ObjectiveManager.Instance.SomeFunction(); // << singleton should be initialized now.
    Destroy(gameObject); //Since it would normally be destroyed during level load, I assume you didn’t need this around any more.
}
```